# sql server insert value in existing column

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update

I have an Employee table as following

[image: TABLE employee]

I want to insert values 4,3,7,8,4,12,10,10,6,NULL,3,10 in existing column [manager] which I had created using query

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee ADD manager INT NULL;
```

Comment: OK what is stopping you doing so?

Comment: You'll need to update each row with the desired column value. For example, `UPDATE dbo.Employee SET manager = 4 WHERE emp_id = 1;UPDATE dbo.Employee SET manager = 3 WHERE emp_id = 2;`, etc.

Comment: Or, rather than multiple `UPDATE` statements, `JOIN` to a `VALUES` table construct and do the whole lot on one go.

Comment: Or use a `CASE` expression. `UPDATE dbo.Employee SET manager = CASE emp_id WHEN 1 THEN 4 WHEN 2 THEN 3 /*....*/ END`

Comment: You could have chosen to *edit top n rows* in SSMS and typed them in quicker than it takes to post on Stack Overflow...

Comment: I don't want to update it line by line. is there any way I can do it in a single go?

Comment: I want a query , i don't want to use SSMS to update is manually.

Comment: *"is there any way I can do it in a single go?"* Yep, check the comments from myself and @MartinSmith .

Comment: @Stu let's be honest, using the "Edit Top n rows" *feature* is rarely a good idea; that thing causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @MartinSmith- Help me with the exact query, please!

Comment: @Larnu -You are so correct, That is probably the last thing to think of.

Comment: I gave the "exact query" - though you would need to add the additional mappings beyond the two examples given

Comment: Personally I've never had any problem using SSMS edit table option for ad-hoc updates, perhaps I've just been lucky!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following is what you need, construct the explicit list of *values* and then simply join to it in an *update*

```
with d as (
    select *
    from (
        values
        (1,4),
        (2,3),
        (3,7),
        (4,8),
        (5,4),
        (6,12),
        (7,10),
        (8,10),
        (9,6),
        (11,3),
        (12,10)  
    )x(emp_id,manager)
)
update e set
    e.manager=d.manager
from d join Employee e on e.emp_id=d.emp_id
```